# How can an accepted answer be chosen from two equally accurate literary analysis answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If both answers are in-depth and provide evidence for their analysis and I see the perspective of both answers, how do I know which I should mark as accepted? On other sites, like Stack Overflow, the accepted answer is easy to determine; it's simply whichever answer solves your problem. However, in the case of literary analysis, I don't really have a problem *per se*, rather just a question about literature that doesn't have one, clear-cut, correct answer.

Comment: As on every other SE site, personal preference. Really, acceptance doesn't really mean much more for the bigger picture than that you liked the answer best. Neither are you required to even accept an answer. It's perfectly fine to keep answers unaccepted for a long time to encourage further answer, and maybe some time an even better one comes around that beats all the existing ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Accept whichever you want.

From the [help centre](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally. Not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer even if a newer, better answer comes along later.

This issue has come up [again](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4603/5373) and [again](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3615/31394) on SE sites where there isn't always a "most correct" answer. The answer is always the same: accept whichever you want. There's absolutely nothing to stop an OP from accepting an answer [which is](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3650/31394) objectively wrong; I've seen accepted answers on various sites with scores in the negative, sometimes even below -20.

There are going to be many questions here on Literature which don't have a single correct answer, or have several answers based on different interpretations and none more correct than any other. If you're in such a situation, you can do one of two things:

- accept the answer which **worked best for you personally** - this could mean the interpretation you favour of a particular literary work, or just the answer you like best for whatever reason;
- just **don't accept an answer at all** - there's no obligation to do so, if you don't feel any of the existing answers resolve your issue. I have questions from 2014 with no accepted answer.

Comment: Quite ironically, I've just run into the same problem described in this question *on this question*.

Comment: I'll give you the checkmark though, as you do support your statement with more evidence.

Comment: @fi12 That must be why they call this the *meta* site ;-)

Comment: You missed a side option: bounty the answer you did not accept, to show that as OP you value it just as much as accepted one

Answer (score 6):

Third option: you don't have to mark *either* of them. Sometimes there's just not a best or correct answer. That's okay, too.

Or, maybe, if you really want to mark an answer, you can decide based on which answer is more researched and thorough, or which answer is presented in the most complete and sound way.

Comment: This is what I'd generally do in this case, but I wasn't sure. +1