# Do we want video embedding to be enabled on Literature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Some Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/278659) have [video embedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/278659) turned on, which means that a Youtube link can be simply pasted into a post as plaintext and it will automatically render as an inline box within which the video can be played without needing to click through to the Youtube site itself.

### **Do we want this to be enabled here on Literature?**

There are nearly 200 posts on this site which contain the URL [youtube.com](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ayoutube.com) or [youtu.be](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ayoutu.be). Admittedly some of these posts wouldn't particularly benefit from having the links embedded, but some of them would: for example, answers to [How do people "kiss their teeth" in Nalo Hopkinson's novels?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8332/17), or [this answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12504/17) or [this one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/13646/17), or [this one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/19056/17) where I even took a screenshot from the video just to embed it as an image. (Apologies for the apparent self-promotion: my own answers, or frustration at not being able to embed videos, are easier to remember, naturally.)

**How much benefit do we see for the site in being able to embed videos?** Obviously we're mostly about written content, so we don't have *as much* need for it as a site like Movies & TV does, but it might be useful if we start getting more questions about, for example, [sign language literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1551/17).

Comment: If YouTube is the only video sharing site from which videos can be embedded, wouldn't it make more sense to word the question as "Do we want YouTube embedding enabled ..."?

Answer (score 0):

#### No, please don't enable YouTube embedding

1. "Nearly 200 posts" on roughly 10070 posts (we had 5125 questions and 5565 answers on the day we graduated) is not even 0.2% and therefore negligible.
2. Those YouTube URLs that we have were added on the assumption that no embedding would take place and I'd rather not check (nearly) 200 posts for unexpected side effects on enabling embedding.
3. It may lead to an increase of low-quality content on the site and make it [less attractive to scholars](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/).
4. It may lead to an increase of inaccessible content on our site, since most videos don't have proper captions / subtitles for the deaf or hard-of-hearing.
5. It adds another source of data tracking and not everyone wants to be tracked by YouTube or Google. (Strictly speaking, Stack Overflow should add an overlay or button over every embedded video that requires the user or visitor to agree to the embedding for exactly this reason, at least in the EU.)
6. It appears to create a [performance penalty for *all* Q&A pages on our site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316007/340816).